# Using Angular controller inside Bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bootstrap-modal

[html]

```
<div class="modal fade" id="proj-edit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" data-remote="update.html">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content" ng-controller="UpdateProjectController"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[javascript]

```
var ProjectApp = angular.module('ProjectApp', ["ui.bootstrap"]);
ProjectApp.controller('UpdateProjectController', ["$scope","$http",  function($scope, $http){
  $scope.message = 'Please enter valid case number';
  $scope.UpdateProject = function(){..do something..};
}]);
```

[update.html]

```
<div class="modal-header" >
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
  <h4 id="myModalLabel" class="modal-title">Update Project</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
  {{message}}
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button type="submit" class="btn blue-soft" ng-click="UpdateProject()">Update</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

Issue: Modal is being invoked from JQuery using *.modal('show')* method. My intention is to render the controller whenever the modal is opened. However, it seems that the modal does not recognise the controller and no message nor function from the controller can be executed. Appreciate your help on this matter. TQ.

Comment: You should use [ui-bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) instead of regular jQuery bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

HI please check the example

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker">
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.18/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.6.0.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3>I'm a modal!</h3>
        </div>
        <form ng-submit="submit()">
          <div class="modal-body">
            <label>User name</label>
            <input type="text" ng-model="user.user" />
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="password" ng-model="user.password" />
            <label>Add some notes</label>
            <textarea rows="4" cols="50" ng-model="user.notes">

</textarea>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
              <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
              <input type="submit" class="btn primary-btn" value="Submit" />
          </div>
        </form>
    </script>

    <button class="btn" ng-click="open()">Open me!</button>
    <div ng-show="selected">Selection from a modal: {{ selected }}</div>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

example.js

```
angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);
var ModalDemoCtrl = function ($scope, $modal, $log) {

    $scope.user = {
        user: 'name',
        password: null,
        notes: null
    };

    $scope.open = function () {

        $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html', // loads the template
            backdrop: true, // setting backdrop allows us to close the modal window on clicking outside the modal window
            windowClass: 'modal', // windowClass - additional CSS class(es) to be added to a modal window template
            controller: function ($scope, $modalInstance, $log, user) {
                $scope.user = user;
                $scope.submit = function () {
                    $log.log('Submiting user info.'); // kinda console logs this statement
                    $log.log(user); 
                    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel'); // dismiss(reason) - a method that can be used to dismiss a modal, passing a reason
                }
                $scope.cancel = function () {
                    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel'); 
                };
            },
            resolve: {
                user: function () {
                    return $scope.user;
                }
            }
        });//end of modal.open
    }; // end of scope.open function
};
```

for reference  http://embed.plnkr.co/As959V/

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the sample. I believe this will obviously work as everything is inside the same html page during redering. In my case, I intentionally put update.html on separate html file. I guess it would not be rendered when the main html page is being called. The reason is update.html is quite a massive form and preferred not to include inside main html file. So, the modal is basically calling the remote html file.

Answer (score 0):

> The reason is update.html is quite a massive form and preferred not to
>   include inside main html file. So, the modal is basically calling the
>   remote html file.

Your remote html file and your modal file maybe using 2 different instances of the UpdateProjectController.

As said by Martijn, you coud use ui-bootstrap for this but if you don't want to, you could solve it by using a directive.

```
// directive to open the modal
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.directive('myModal', myModal);

myModal.$inject = [];

function myModal() {

        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: link
        }

        function link($scope, $element, $attributes) {
            $element.click(function (event) {
                angular.element($attributes.modalId).modal();
            });
        }
}

app.controller('ModalCtrl', ModalCtrl);

ModalCtrl.$inject = [];

function ModalCtrl() {
    $scope.message = 'Please enter valid case number';
    $scope.UpdateProject = function(){..do something..};

}
```

> Modal is being invoked from JQuery using .modal('show') method.

So in case you use a button to do this  render the modal, you could easily include the directive as an attribute to the modal instead of ng-click()

Lastly, include the modal file in your template file

```
 <body>
         <div ng-controller="UpdateProjectController">
             // So in case you use a button to do this render the modal,
             // you could easily include the directive as an attribute to the modal instead of ng-click()
             <a href="javascript:;" my-modal modal-id="#modalUpdateProject">
                 Update Project
             </a>
         </div>

         <!-- modals -->
         <div ng-controller="ModalCtrl">
             <ng-include src="'path/to/modal.html'"></ng-include>
         </div>
         <!-- end modals -->
     </body>
```